# Может ли std::initializer_list перемещать объекты? С++

Tags: c++, инициализация

Нужно ли мувить объект в список инициализации или это бессмысленно? Допустим есть вектор строк, который инициализируется при помощи списка инициализации:

```
std::string s1{"fff"};
std::string s2{"f1f1f1"};
std::vector<std::string> vec({std::move(s1), std::move(s2)});
```

Переместятся ли строки в вектор или же *std::initializer* не поддерживает перемещение и всё равно их скопирует?

А если перемещается лишь один аргумент?

```
std::vector<std::string> vec({std::move(s1), s2});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `initializer_list` мувнуть можно. Из него - не получится, потому что элементы константные.

Comment: Получается, что мувить при использовании списка инициализации смысла нет? К увеличению производительности это не приведет?

Comment: @ComeInRage Есть смысл. Хотя бы от одной из двух копий избавитесь.